# Unit Testing Vue with Jest and Vue Test Utils

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm brand new at Unit Testing with vue.
I'm trying to unit test a navigation vue component. I started out easy, I just wanted to test a method that just makes a boolean false(triggered by an on click). I am also using vuetify. I somewhat managed to mimic a button and then my hope is that the variable I'm passing (showLoginDrawer) returns false in my unit test. My error is TypeError: _vm.is.has is not a function which relates to a different part of my code, I think I'm missing something but I couldn't find anything online about it.

Below I've included the component and my testing file.

```
//Nav.vue
<template>
  <v-btn
        :to="{ name: 'home' }"
        aria-label="Home button"
        @click="hideDiv()"
   >
   </v-btn>

      <div>
        <transition name="nav-fade">
          <component v-bind:is="drawerSection"></component>
        </transition>
      </div>

</template>
<script>
     data() {
      return {
        drawerSection: function () {
          if (this.is.has('learning')) {
            return 'nav-learning'
          } else {
            return 'nav-explore'
          }
        },
      }
    },
    methods: {
      hideDiv() {
        if (!this.appState.restrictedAccessAlert)
          this.appState.showLoginDrawer = false
      }
}
</script>
<style>//disregard</style>
```

```
//Nav.spec.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import { shallowMount, mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Nav from '@/components/Nav'


const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(Vuetify)
localVue.use(Vuex)

describe('Testing Nav component', () => {
    let vuetify
    beforeEach(() => {
      vuetify = new Vuetify()
    })
    test('Test Button click when logged out', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Navigation, {
      data() {
        return {
          appState: {
            showLoginDrawer: true,
            lastCapabilityPath: '',
            restrictedAccessAlert: false,
          },
          is: 'learning',
          localVue,
          vuetify,
        }
      },
    })

    const event = jest.fn()
    const button = wrapper.findAll('.v-btn').at(0)
    expect(button.text()).toContain('My Profile')

    button.vm.$on('click', event)
    expect(event).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0)
    expect(wrapper.vm.showLoginDrawer).toBeTruthy()
    button.trigger('click')
    expect(event).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(wrapper.vm.showLoginDrawer).toBeFalsy()
  })
})
```

I get the error:

`TypeError: _vm.is.has is not a function`

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Because `is` property is not defined in the code you posted. This is what the error says.

Comment: when adding is I get TypeError: _vm.is.has is not a function. I didn't write this code and I can't find has anywhere so I assumed it was a built in of some sort. (Also sorry I forgot to add it int he code above, I was deleting some portion that was console log and stuff and I accidentally deleted that )

Answer (score 1):

Oh my mistake was that has() is a set function thus it won't work with a string so I had to make it equal to a set.

Updated code:

```
  test('Test Basic HTML rendering', () => {
    const is = new Set(['learning', 'b', 'c'])

    const wrapper = mount(Navigation, {
      data() {
        return {
          appState: {
            showLoginDrawer: true,
            lastCapabilityPath: '',
            restrictedAccessAlert: false,
          },
          is,
          localVue,
          vuetify,
        }
      },
    })
    wrapper.vm.$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndUp = true
    expect(wrapper.html()).toContain('Log-in')
    // check the name of the component
    expect(wrapper.vm.$options.name).toMatch('NavProfile')
  })
```

Comment: Could you demonstrate with an inclusion of the code what was changed?

Comment: Yes! Just updated my response @Paul Williams

Answer (score 0):

Please try use `async` & `await`, maybe every event call is asynchronous

```js
describe('Testing Nav component', () => {
    let vuetify
    beforeEach(() => {
        vuetify = new Vuetify()
    })

    test('Test Button click when logged out', async () => { // use async
        const wrapper = mount(Navigation, {
            data() {
                return {
                    appState: {
                        showLoginDrawer: true,
                        lastCapabilityPath: '',
                        restrictedAccessAlert: false,
                    },
                    is: 'learning',
                    localVue,
                    vuetify,
                }
            },
        })

        const event = jest.fn()
        const button = wrapper.findAll('.v-btn').at(0)
        expect(button.text()).toContain('My Profile')

        button.vm.$on('click', event)
        expect(event).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0)
        expect(wrapper.vm.showLoginDrawer).toBeTruthy()

        // Try use await at every event
        await button.trigger('click')
        expect(event).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
        expect(wrapper.vm.showLoginDrawer).toBeFalsy()
    })
})
```